# Next.js 13 imports

Tags: next.js

I work on a Next.js 13 app and everything worked fine until out of nowhere I started having problems with imports, the first errors where for any import from '@/..' (should direct to src. folder), then I changed all '@/' to '../' and it looked like it worked but I got another importing error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'date-fns'
1 | import React from 'react';

> 2 | import { formatDistanceToNow, parseISO } from 'date-fns';
> 3 |
> 4 | const RecipeCard = ({ recipe }) => {
> 5 |   const { title, description, tags, created_at } = recipe;

[https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found`](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found%60)

worth mentioning I installed 'date-fns' and it worked before, nothing really changed

Thanks,
Or

I tried to change 'jsconfig.json' file like I saw online but no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.